# iOS Swift - Declare external function inside @IBAction func

Tags: ios, swift, function, ibaction, xcode6.3

I need to call some other function when UIButton is pressed (in my case pass data from UIDatePicker and UITextField to EKCalendar to create an event, so I can not just write it inside IBAction func {})
Here is my function:

```
func insertEvent(store: EKEventStore) {

        let calendars = store.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent)
            as! [EKCalendar]

        for calendar in calendars {

            if calendar.title == "todo" {

                let startDate = myDatePicker.date

                let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(2 * 60 * 60)

                // Create Event
                var event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
                event.calendar = calendar

                event.title = nameTextField.text
                event.startDate = startDate
                event.endDate = endDate

                // Save Event in Calendar
                var error: NSError?
                let result = store.saveEvent(event, span: EKSpanThisEvent, error: &error)

                if result == false {
                    if let theError = error {
                        println("An error occured \(theError)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What should I write in :

```
@IBAction func addReminder(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

to call my function I wrote above.

I've tried just call it by typing `insertEvent()` inside `IBAction func {}`, but in gives me warning "missing argument for parameter #1 in call..." also tried to call in with parameter and it also gives me warning...
I also tried to create an outlet for button (not action) type of segue and then access in with

```
func addReminder(sender: UIButton) { 
    if sender === addReminder {}
}
```

but it gives me the same errors... what a curse!

How could I assign this function to a button, maybe there is another way?

P.S.: I am Xcode 6.3

Comment: insertEvent(store: EKEventStore) as the declaration says

Comment: when I try this I also  get
cannot invoke insertEvent with an argument...

Comment: You tried with passing the parameter or just calling insertEvent()?

Comment: no, I haven't. Could you please write an example?

Comment: You wrote @IBAction func addReminder(sender: UIButton) { insertEvent()  } or func addReminder(sender: UIButton) { insertEvent(store: VALUE OF TYPE EKEventStore) }? <- This is the correct way because you need to provide the “store” value

Comment: I can't, always gives my a mistake. I wrote above...

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is in how you declared `insertEvent`. You have two options.

Declare it like you have - but understand you need to declare the parameter in your call:

```
func insertEvent(store: EKEventStore) {
    // do something here
}
```

And to call it:

```
@IBAction func addReminder(sender: UIButton) {
    insertEvent(store: myEKEventStoreVariable)
}
```

The more "Swiftier" way is to put an underscore in your function declaration, which makes the function call no need the parameter:

```
func insertEvent(_ store: EKEventStore) {
    // do something here, again, note the underscore
}
```

And the call is:

```
@IBAction func addReminder(sender: UIButton) {
    insertEvent(myEKEventStoreVariable)
}
```

Essentially you were correct - you cannot "embed" the function declaration inside your IBAction, so you needed to move that logic into an "outside" function. But you declared the function in a way to require the parameter name.

Comment: not working in my case... Please, anyone competent here? I just want to execute my function when UIButton is pressed... and I can not write the whole function inside @IBAction func {} ! Your suggestions, please!

Comment: Um, apologies for not being "competent". Could you explain what exactly isn't working? It's a pretty simple skeleton I gave you - if you add two `print("statement")` or better yet, breakpoints... one inside your `IBAction`, one inside the outside function... you should find that either both are hit or else you have the issue. Hopefully that's a "competent" addition! Good luck.